# How would I match a range with regex, with limited regex rules

Tags: regex, google-cloud-platform

I have a list of items with the format abc-defg-[0000-9999].  For example, abc-defg-0904, abc-defg-0590.

I'm trying to search and delete all of these items.

I have these rules from the SDK I am using, but I'm not too familiar with regex, is it possible to do what I want with these rules?

ERROR: (gcloud.compute.images.delete) Could not fetch resource:
 - Invalid value 'abc-defg-\d{4}'. Values must match the following regular expression: 'a-z?|[1-9][0-9]{0,19}'

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
[a-z]{3}\-[a-z]{4}\-[0-9]{4}
```

The `[a-z]{3}` match arrangement of alphabetic letters `[a-z]` with length 3 `{3}`.

The `[a-z]{4}` is the same with length 4.

This is the same logical but with integer `[0-9]`.

Answer (score 0):

i think what the error message wants to tell you, is that it will accept any specific id, but not a regex as parameter.

the regex that is asked for in the message however seems to be invalid, because it expects a string "a-" followed by an optional "z" OR any number beginning with an 1, which is not nearly matching your id format.